# Bash script for exiting linux using sudo shutdown

Tags: raspbian

I have a raspberry pi and run dosbox from the command line. Is it possible to write a script to run dosbox and shutdown Linux "sudo halt" after i have exited dosbox.

something like

```
#!/bin/bash
#run dosbox 
dosbox
#after exiting dosbox shutdown Linux
sudo halt
exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The code

```
echo "sudo shutdown -h now" | /usr/bin/at now + 10 min >/dev/null 2>&1
exit 0
```

will give the instruction to shut down the Pi (inserting a suitable delay) and exit the script cleanly. Here we have redirected the output to make it 'silent'.

Comment: `sudo shutdown -h +10` wold have the same effect without calling `at`. I'm pretty sure that the OP wanted the Raspberry Pi to shutdown cleanly as soon as dosbox had finished, though.

Comment: I want the script detect when dosbox has closed then halt linux

Comment: I think your original script will? It just wouldn't exit your script cleanly, whereas a small delay would.

Comment: If there's nothing else for the script to do, there's no need to exit it "cleanly".